# redirect_to external url passing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I need to pass params in a redirect_to method to an external url...

I know that I can do something like this with a redirect:

```
redirect_to my_url_path(param1: "foo", param2: "bar")
```

But I want to do this with an external url. For example:

```
redirect_to "www.example.externaldomain.com/process/XIGHTDJTRIDEOR", param1: "foo", param2: "bar"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the ruby URI module and create your own helper:

```
def generate_url(url, params = {})
  uri = URI(url)
  uri.query = params.to_query
  uri.to_s
end
```

Then just get the url:

```
redirect_to generate_url("www.example.externaldomain.com/process/XIGHTDJTRIDEOR", :param1 => "foo", :param2 => "bar")
```